# z3: print a very long assertion

Tags: z3, smt, z3py

Take the following as an example.

```py
trues = [True] * 1000
a = z3.And(trues)
```

So `a` is a conjunction of 1000 `True`s. Note that this is not a practical example since `a` is logically equivalent to `True`.

If we `print(a)`, the full assertion is not showed. Instead, the result is ended with `...)`.

To print the full assertion, one solution I found is to print the *s-expression* of `a`. That is, `print(a.sexpr())`. In this way, all of the 1000 `True`s are showed.

So my question: is there a better way to print a very long assertion like `a`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure. Try:

```py
import z3

z3.set_option(max_args=10000000, max_lines=1000000, max_depth=10000000, max_visited=1000000)

trues = [True] * 1000
a = z3.And(trues)

print(a)
```

You can play with the numbers to `set_option` to get something more reasonable for your use case.

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I need.